# Unable to reference parent component data object

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure this out.

I'm trying to reference a JSON object (or any props at this point) in the function body of a child component.  I tested whether I was able to reference data in the JSON by typing out the full expression in a variable in the function body of the child component but autocomplete isn't working for any of the properties passed through props.

Note, I removed much of the structure of the JSON object to keep this post concise but it does contain more data.

My code:

Parent Component:

```
export default function SproutStudioSvgContainer() {

const initialCanvasDataModel = {
    "data": {}
}


// const [canvasDataModel, dispatchCanvasDataModel] = useReducer(SproutReducer, initialCanvasDataModel);

// Utility: getCanvasRootNodeFromUrl()
// This will either be a userId or branchId
const [canvasRootNode, setCanvasRootNode] = useState({ nodeId: '1' });
const [windowRootNode, setWindowRootNode] = useState({ nodeId: '1' });
const [allowedBloomLevel, setAllowedBloomLevel] = useState(3);

return (
    < Fragment >
        <svg id='sprout-root-svg' height='100%' width='100%' viewBox='0 0 1000 1000'>
            <g id='root-node-container'>
                {/* Positioned by default to the bottom-center of the SVG canvas. */}
                <g id='root-sprout-node'>
                    <RootContainer myData={initialCanvasDataModel} />
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </Fragment >
  )
}
```

Child component:

```
const RootContainer = (props) => {
let s = props.myData
console.log(s) // returns JSON data but doesn't autocomplete any properties in the JSON
console.log(props) // returns props passed, but doesn't autocomplete any of them.

return (
    <Fragment>
        {/* <RootNode
            // title={rootNodeTitle} nodeId={props.nodeId}
            nodeType='root'
            x={props.initialCanvasDataModel}
            y={props.y}
            height={props.height}
            width={props.width}
        /> */}
        {/* <CollectionNodeContainer branchId={props.branchId} /> */}
        {/* <SubBranchesContainer
            parentNodeId={props.nodeId}
            canvasDataModel={props.canvasDataModel}
        /> */}
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default RootContainer;
```

Comment: Is the problem that the props are not correct or simply that autocomplete does not work on props?

Comment: I believe they're correct?  I made a basic parent and child component and tried to access some generic props from the Child but wasn't able to in the function body or the return JSX.

When you say the props might be incorrect, could you elaborate on that?  Is there anything that you see above that raises concern?  I'm fairly new to this so I'm still learning and open to suggestions.

The autocomplete is definitely not working though.

Comment: Since I'm using TypeScript, is the problem that I need to define the shape of the props object in advance?   I'm fine with doing that, but I was previously able to use intellisense to dynamically generate autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that a type has not been attached to the object. If you create a type and attach it it should work. The type in your case could be:

```
type myType = {
    data: object
}
```

And the object you are using as props needs to be declared to be this type:

```
const initialCanvasDataModel: myType = {
```

And then you can extend the type when there are more children. For this to work i do not believe you can use props, but you can get the props like this:

```
const RootContainer = ({myData}: {myData: myType}) => {
```

Now you should be able to use autocomplete as normal.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I just spent the last 2 hours reading up on this and came to the same conclusion.  I appreciate you!!

The only thing that's still a bit strange to me...  I was working on this project for the last few days and the autocomplete was working but out of nowhere just stopped.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what I saw, but this wasn't an issue until very recently.

Nonetheless, when I do as you suggested, it did work so that's enough for me.  I guess I'll just need to use TS as it was intended instead of relying on inference.